# mySQL SELECT and COUNT speed query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

I'm using PDO, and I need to know how many rows are returned with a SELECT statement. My question is, is the following slower, the same, or faster than doing it in two queries? PHPMyAdmin will tell me how long just the SELECT statement, takes, but not just the COUNT statement, so I'm having trouble telling how long a query takes.

Query in question:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) from table) AS count FROM table
```

Faster, same or slower than splitting it into two queries?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there's some sort of experiment you could devise for testing this?

Comment: Having more complicated queries can take more time as well as having the large number of data to be returned from the database. The larger and more complicated the queries the slower/ more time needed to execute it.

Comment: "Faster, same or slower than splitting it into two queries?" --- it worth splitting, not only because of speed but mostly because the current query makes no sense. Seriously, what did you want to express with it?

Comment: @Aljie, it's two queries, and assuming MySQL will cache the second one, then if anything it would be the SAME time, which is what I'm hoping for (but faster would be even better), that way I don't have to have two queries.

Comment: @zerkms, the goal would be to not have to have two queries to keep track of. How would it be faster? Does MySQL not cache?

Comment: @David: I would raise the question about logic behind this query first. `Jon 3; David 3; Ivan 3` - Suppose you have returned 3 rows. What is the reason to return `3` here? You **ALREADY** retrieved all the rows, cannot you just count them? What does `3` (as a rows number) has in common for a particular row? "How would it be faster?" --- what do you know about mysql performance optimization? Do you realize the execution plan for the query you provided in the question?

Comment: @zerkms, because when I do a ->fetch() statement, I don't know how many rows I have. And if you've you much with PDO, then you know that there's no reliable rowCount() function with a SELECT statement. And about optimization, I know nill. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @David: until you get into optimization and understand how to optimize *properly* - don't even try. Seriously, applying random thoughts would make everything even worse. So until that - just follow the semantics and perform as much reasonable queries as necessary. In this case - counting and selecting data have nothing in common thus should be performed separately

Comment: @zerkms, fair enough. What do you think of the latest answer that was just posted? Can you put your answer here in the comments, and whether or not that's a good / bad idea as well? I like being able to mark a question as solved.

Comment: @David: the first performance optimization rule: only optimize what is slow. So before trying to optimize *anything* - ensure it is the slowest/most inefficient part of the application.

Comment: @zerkms Understood. Can you put your answer into a real answer so you can get credit for your help?

Comment: @David: just accept Gordon, he provided a decent answe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this query as:

```
SELECT t.*, const.totalcount
FROM table t cross join
     (select count(*) as totalcount from table) const;
```

This may or may not be faster than running two queries.  Two queries involve "query running" overhead -- compiling the query, transmitting the data back and forth.  This adds another column, so it increases the total amount of data in the result set.

Comment: It worth mentioning that optimizations that turn semantic data into a mess only make sense when they make sense, not just as a "why not" step.

Answer (score 1):

Two queries is going to be faster. What you have is a dependent subquery, it's going to run for every record in the parent. If it's a MyISAM table, the subquery will be very fast and you may not notice it with a small number of records.

Do an EXPLAIN on it and see what MySQL reports back.

Comment: Not very enlightening, maybe you can gather information from it? http://imgur.com/zif1K0n

Comment: @David: until you start understanding `EXPLAIN`, indexes, etc just **DON'T** try to optimize queries. Just because **IT IS** a complicated subject and random attempts (as you already tried) make things only worse. And stop thinking 2 queries are worse than 1, it's not true. Not even close.